# Refresh template custom control after clearing and re-adding MergedDictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, resourcedictionary

**The situation**

I made a `custom control` *MessageBar* that has a style defined in a resource dictionary. This control has a `dependency property` *Message* that, like the name says, will contain a message.

```
public class MessageBar : Control
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(MessageBar),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnMessageChanged));

        static MessageBar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MessageBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MessageBar)));
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnMessageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBar messageBar = (MessageBar)d;

            if (e.NewValue != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewValue.ToString()))
            {
                messageBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                if (messageBar.textBlock == null)
                    messageBar.textBlock = messageBar.GetChildOfType<TextBlock>();

           // Lots of unnecessary code
            }
}
```

*Style*

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MessageBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:MessageBar}">
                    <Border Background="LightYellow"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                            CornerRadius="0,0,10,10">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Margin="10,0,10,0">
                            <!-- Actual text -->
                            <TextBlock Padding="4,2,4,2"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       x:Name="tbText"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Message}"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

When the application starts, the default style is loaded in the `merged dictionaries`. After the user logs in, the style that the user chose (this can be different of the default style) is loaded in the `merged dictionaries`. Reloading the style happens by clearing the `merged dictionaries` and re-adding the correct `resource dictionaries` to the `merged dictionaries`.

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = ...
});
// Adding happens a few times.
```

The new style is correctly loaded and this is also visible in the UI. The UI changes correctly.

**The problem**

The problem happens when after clearing and re-adding the merged dictionaries, I try to find the child of type `TextBlock` in the `OnMessageChanged` method.

```
messageBar.textBlock = messageBar.GetChildOfType<TextBlock>();
```

*I am 100% sure that there is nothing wrong with my `GetChildOfType<>()` method. It works correctly when used somewhere else.*

When I execute this after re-adding, there are no child elements of `MessageBar`. `ChildrenCount` is 0.

When the merged dictionaries aren't cleared and re-added, there is a child element of type `TextBlock` found. This is what I want.

My guess is that after clearing and re-adding, the `MessageBar` doesn't have a correct reference to the style. And because of that, the template isn't applied.

**What I already tried**

I already tried overriding the `ApplyTemplate()` and `OnStyleChanged()` methods of the `MessageBar` control. But nothing works.

**Question**

How can I reload the style so that I (the `GetChildOfType<TextBlock>()` method) can find the `TextBlock` to set my message in the `OnMessageChanged` method.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings Loetn.

Comment: Try messageBar.ApplyTemplate() before calling GetChildOfType

Comment: @ethicallogics That did the trick. Thanks a lot! It can be so easy that I didn't even think about this... If you write this in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: :) I wrote it as answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try messageBar.ApplyTemplate() before calling GetChildOfType
```